# SSRS: How to show subreport's name in master report

Tags: ssrs-2008

Can you tell me how to display the subreport's name in the master report's footer? There is the Globals!ReportName variable but it contains the master report's name.

Comment: There's no built-in function to lookup the subreport name. The only way this might be possible is with a custom function that checks the report components to try and find the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Steven.
Can you give me an example how I can provide a function and use it in another report. 
Thank you in advance.